# Formatting of JPanel with JTextField within a JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing

I am using a `JTabbedPane` to control a few panels, each containing fields for the user to enter information. The intention is that the user might fill them in  any order, and may go back to change the information previously entered.

```
JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
tabs.add("Attributes", attributesPanel);
...
frame.add(tabs);
```

Each of the panels uses a `GridBagLayout` along with `GridBagConstraints` to format everything. When I don't enter anything and change tabs, everything seems okay. However, when I enter any information within any of the `JTextField`s and change tabs, returning to the tab will show everything bunched up within the center of the frame.

[image: Crushed image is crushed.]

Does anyone know why that may be? Again, this only occurs if I actually enter something in the text fields...

In the panels, everything is initialized in the constructor. Here is some partial code:

```
protected EntityBuilderAttributesPanel() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(EntityBuilder.PANEL_WIDTH, EntityBuilder.PANEL_HEIGHT));

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

        entityIdLabel = new JLabel("Entity Unique Identity");
        entityIdTextField = new JTextField();
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        add(entityIdLabel, c);
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        add(entityIdTextField, c);

        entityNameLabel = new JLabel("Entity Name");
        entityNameTextField = new JTextField();
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        add(entityNameLabel, c);
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        add(entityNameTextField, c);

        space_01 = new JLabel();
        space_01.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(EntityBuilder.PANEL_WIDTH, 25));
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        add(space_01, c);

        attributesLabel = new JLabel("Entity Attributes");
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 3;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        add(attributesLabel, c);
        attributes = new JList(EntityAttribute.values());
        attributes.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        attributes.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
        attributes.setVisibleRowCount(10);
        JScrollPane listScroller = new JScrollPane(attributes);
        listScroller.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(EntityBuilder.PANEL_WIDTH, 400));
        listScroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 4;
        c.gridwidth = 4;
        add(listScroller, c);
[...]
```

Comment: Are you doing anything when people change tabs or enter data?

Comment: Nope! I haven't added change listeners or action listeners, and I don't want to...

Comment: Are you re-using any GridBagContraints, or layout managers?

Comment: Do you use `setXXXSize()` or `ipadx/ipady` on components ?

Comment: I don't use ipadx/y, but I do call setPreferredSize(). Everything is set in the constructor of the JPanel itself. Let me add to the question.

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), if we can't run it and see for ourselves we can't solve it. (Make sure it's a minimal example, 2 tabs should be enough etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
listScroller.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(EntityBuilder.PANEL_WIDTH, 400));
```

The problem is probably because you are trying to hardcode a preferred size. If a component can't be displayed at its preferred size then GridBagLayout uses the minimum size.

Instead use a method like list.setVisibleRows(...) and let the list component determine the height/width.

```
//entityNameTextField = new JTextField();
entityNameTextField = new JTextField(10);
```

Specify a number when you create the text field and again let the text field determine a reasonable size.

```
//space_01.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(EntityBuilder.PANEL_WIDTH, 25));
Box.createVerticalStrut(25);
```

Swing already provides a transparent component you can use instead of using a JLabel. The Box component will be more efficient since it doesn't use a UI like a JLabel does so there is nothing to paint.